# scroll not working while dragging using bs-sortable angular 4

Tags: angular, scrollable, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-bootstrap bs-sortable for sorting the items. But the problem is the items are not scrolling while dragging. In chrome its default scroll is working, but not in any other browsers.

Please refer this link for more details:

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/sortable#sortable-component

I have added the screenshot : 
[image]

I just want the container to scroll automatically when the dragged item reaches the end of the page.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Share your code

Comment: @Roy : you can refer the code in "https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/sortable#basic  " this page under basic , i have used the same one .

Comment: Do you enable support for other browsers?

Comment: How do I enable it ??? , For Google its the default scroll its working, how do i make this work in other browsers.

Comment: src/polyfills.ts  in your app

Comment: @Roy : Can you please be more clear regarding this ... What am i suppose to do in src/polyfills.ts file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178350/discussion-between-roy-g-and-a4u).